# Is there a macro that defines the limit of non-significant digits when printing a double floating point number in C?

Tags: c, runtime, libc

When using printf with a large precision and a double floating point number, there is rounding that occurs on non-significant digits (when the trailing 0's start). I'm wondering if there is a macro that defines the limit/amount of digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    const double x = 2.0 / 3.0;
    int precision = 100;
    printf("%.*f\n", precision, x);
    printf("%d\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0.6666666666666666296592325124947819858789443969726562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
17
```

The repeating 6's are the significant digits, while the following numbers are non-significant digits, which are then rounded at some point (where is this point defined?) and followed with repeating 0's.

Comment: For floating-point formats using base two, rounding occurs on the binary representation of a number, not on decimal digits. Mathematically, there are no “significant” or “non-significant” decimal digits for this purpose. There is a macro that tells how many decimal digits can be preserved by a single conversion of a number to floating-point and back, but this does not tell you how many digits in a computed result from other operations are “significant” or “correct” because rounding errors can compound or cancel to make the final error anything from zero to infinity, depending on circumstances.

Comment: No, there is no macro that tells you where the zeros start. To find the starting point of the zeros, convert the `double` to a string, e.g. with `sprintf`, and then scan backwards through the zeros to find the first non-zero digit.

Comment: @user3386109: If the question is where the zeros necessarily start, and `FLT_RADIX` is 2, there is a macro that gives it, `DBL_MANT_DIG`, due to the nature of the mathematics involved.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed, but certainly only if the ULP is set. And perhaps only if the number is between 0.5 and 1.0 (the effect of the exponent on the number of digits is not entirely clear to me).

Comment: Roughly speaking, when the exponent is greater than 1, each fractional binary bit adds 1 fractional decimal digit, but an average of about 3.3 whole binary bits are needed for each whole decimal digit. So the number of digits before the zeros decreases as the exponent increases.

Comment: If rounding occurs on the binary representation of a number, how is this done or where is this defined?

Comment: The C standard specifies, partly, how floating-point numbers are represented in C 2018 5.2.4.2.2. It does not specify complete rules for floating-point operations. Most C implementations largely follow IEEE 754, with some deviations or shortcomings that are significant at times. Most C implementations use a base of two for floating-point, a consequence of which is you should think of numbers using binary numerals and real numbers (abstract points on a line), not decimal. Decimal is relevant only for viewing values, not for understanding the arithmetic.

Comment: Valeria, if your machine is using binary floating point (highly likely), then you've shown the _exact_ value of `x` there - no rounding when printed.  I recommend reading [Float Precision–From Zero to 100+ Digits](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/), and the many other good floating-point articles on Bruce's site.

Comment: If a number x = b.c where b and c are binary representations, then the last decimal digit when printed is at the position of the last set bit in c. For IEEE 754, you could obtain an upper limit by knowing the size of the mantissa and get the exponent either with bit manipulations or some log_2 function. Obtaining the number of trailing binary unset bits is tricky though. I'm not sure you could or should do it with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

See C11 [§5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types `<float.h>`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2).  You're probably looking for `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.  Note that the number shown in the standard is the minimum acceptable value — your implementation probably has a higher value.

> - number of decimal digits, *n*, such that any floating-point number with *p* radix *b* digits can be rounded to a floating-point number with *n* decimal digits and back again without change to the value,
>
>   ```
>   { p log10 b        if b is a power of 10
>   {
>   { [^1 + p log10 b^] otherwise
>   ```
>
> `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG                                   6`
> `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG                                  10`
> `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG                                 10`

That may not be exactly what you're after, but it is the closest approximation in the standard.

Comment: In my case, DBL_DECIMAL_DIG returns 17, but there are more than 17 digits in the number I posted. It's being rounded some time after this, which I'm trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: Only 17 digits a reliable; after that, you are dealing with noise.  Look in the section of the standard that I linked to.  There might be something else that tells you that you want to know.